# Is there a mode for phpBB?

Tags: major-mode, font-lock, minor-mode

I'm using the "[It's all Text" addon for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/its-all-text/) so I can edit textarea's in Emacs. As I spend some time on a phpBB forum, I was wondering if there is an Emacs mode for phpBB with it's syntax of using `[tag]` and `[/tag]`. I'm mainly interested in syntax highlighting, so if no phpBB mode exists, is there something that comes close?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is [`bbcode-mode`](https://github.com/ejmr/bbcode-mode).  After installing it (e.g. from melpa) add this to your configuration file:

```
(require 'bbcode-mode)
```

There are also [other modes for BBCode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BbCode).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't know the language was called 'BBcode' so I only searched for 'phpbBB mode'.